# Understanding nested loops with index modification

Tags: c++

I have a homework problem that asks me to describe, in several sentences, what the following piece of code does, but the homework has no solutions. I'm trying to understand what it does so I can prepare for following evaluations.

It loops twice up to the number, but the loop condition changes every time there is a multiple of 3 or 5, which is confusing me.

```
unsigned int g(unsigned int l) {
    unsigned int i { 0 };
    unsigned int j { 0 };
    unsigned int k { 0 };
    while (i < l) {
        while (j < l) {
            if (j % 3 == 0) {
                i = i - 1;
                j = j + 1;
                break;
            }
            if (j % 5 == 0) {
                i = i - 1;
                j = j + 1;
                break;
            }
            k += j;
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

I thought it counted the square of the number minus the occurrences of multiples of 3 and 5 below n (n - multiples of 3 - multiples of 5)^2 , but it comes off by 1 or 2 every so often. Am I just missing something small at the end or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "with no solutions"?

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry I meant the homework had no solutions, hence why I'm asking here

Comment: Did you debug this? It would allow you to at least watch what actually happens. Describing probably becomes easier then.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah I did, I can post it if you'd like. Like I said I have an approximation that is very close (+ around 25%) but I can't quite figure out what it does, or why. The exam won't have a compiler (it's on paper) so I would have had to have done it without the debugger anyways.

Comment: Did you try printing the result, e.g. for all numbers 0..250?

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm a SO noob, that was for my edit...

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes that's what I did, and I can't understand how the output relates to the input exactly

Comment: I understand the lack of compiler and debugger in the exam. Of course you need to train for paper exam. So I think you can use the tools now, but also practice using pen and paper to act compiler/computer yourself. Make a table with all variables, and add rows for each change of any variable. Busy work.... Good luck.

Comment: If you show the table, it improves the question and you only need to ask the more specific (and own research heavy) "How can I describe this process in English prose?". Maybe it ends up being a prime or something else which can be described in one word. Probably not, teacher seems to expect longer prose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code just adds all numbers up to (but not including) `l` that aren't divisible by 3 or 5.

Incrementing `j` is the main loop control used here. You'll see that each iteration adds 1 to it no matter which branch executes.

Decrementing `i` is necessary because of the `break` statements. Basically, it's just to keep the place in the loop, i.e. `i = i - 1`, break out of the inner loop, `i = i + 1`, continue outer loop & then the inner loop picks up from the next `j`.

The function could be expressed with a single loop like this & still get the same results:

```
unsigned int g(unsigned int l) {
    unsigned int j { 0 };
    unsigned int k { 0 };

    while (j < l) {
        if (!(j % 3 == 0 || j % 5 == 0)) {
            //Add to total if not divisible
            k += j;
        }

        ++j;    //Loop control
    }

    return k;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to figure it out (as my answer suggests) but I couldn't understand the --i. That makes it much more clear. Tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering about the solution, it sums the numbers less than l that are not multiples of 3 or 5. A simpler version of the code can be found below.

```
unsigned int n{0};
unsigned int sum{0};
while(n < l){
    if((n % 3 != 0) && (n % 5 != 0)){
        sum += n;
    }
    ++n;
}
```